# Llave de 3DES en python

Tags: python, criptografía

Estoy estudiando Cryptografia por primera vez, estoy viendo cifrador 3DES y debo programarlo con ayuda de cualquier librería, en este caso use PyCryptodome, el punto es que debo mostrar la llaves que usare para cifrar, y si mal no entiendo que deben ser 3 de 56 bits

En python estoy usando este codigo

```
from email import message
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import base64

while True:
    try:
       key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(get_random_bytes(24))
       print(key)
       archivo = open("key.txt","w")
       message = str(key)
       message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
       b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
       b64_k = b64_bytes.decode('ascii')
       archivo.write(b64_k)
       archivo.close()
       break
     except ValueError:  
          pass
```

Código que esta en la documentación pero modificado para regresar la llave en base64, pero regresa una sola cadena, como puedo hacer para imprimir las 3 llaves, habrá algo que no estaré entendiendo? Y cuando crea la llave no entiendo porque pide 24 bytes, además cuando imprimo la llave o cuento la cantidad de caracteres a veces son mas y a veces son menos, a que se debe?, puedo imprimir las cadenas por separado para analizarlas?
Si alguien puede iluminarme me ayudaría mucho a entender mas y claro cumplir con mis deberes, muchas gracias..!! Buen dia :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la ejecución del programa 3 veces y se ven claramente cadenas de distinto tamaño
Estoy un poco perdido la verdad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo la parte de la criptografía, pero tu código no se ajusta a lo que necesitas.

El mayor problema es que abres el archivo con opción "w" en cada iteración del `while`. Eso significa que el archivo es recreado en cada pasada, y nunca tendrá más que una llave.

La solución es crear el archivo fuera de la iteración.

También debes cambiar la iteración. Si quieres generar tres llaves, mejor usa un `for llave in range(3)`.

Con eso el código queda:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import base64

with open("key.txt","w") as archivo:
    for llave in range(3):
        try:
           key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(get_random_bytes(24))
           print(len(key), key)
           message = str(key)
           message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
           b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
           b64_k = b64_bytes.decode('ascii')
           archivo.write(b64_k)
        except ValueError:
           pass
```

Las llaves son siempre de 24 bytes de largo, como lo puedes comprobar. Te parecen de largos distintos pues estás mirando su representación *codificada*.

El caso es que la llave puede contener cualquier valor binario, y para poder almacenarlo/transmitirlo sin pérdida, es necesario *codificarlo* en algún formato. Esta transformación puede crear una representación más larga que el original, pero cuando la necesites usar, sólo tienes que *decodificarlo*